# Get latest ItemID from list with workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-lookup

how can I get the latest ItemID from a list with a Sharepoint workflow?
Like these SQL Statement:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM list WHERE title = "example1"
```

Is there any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TSQL-like language for querying SP lists is called CAML.
To get the latest ID you can construct CAML to sort items by `Created` date from newest to oldest, while setting `rowlimit` = 1

To CAML-query lists in SharePoint Designer workflow one can use 'CAML in REST' approach. OData will work too, just don't use both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

When you use the action"Create list item"  in your workflow, a  variable   named create appears in the action. The action also has the output  clause which is denoted by (Output to Variable: create).

```
     At the workflow's run time, the variable create stores the list item ID of the item that is created in the other list. 

    So you can use the variable :create to update the column in the listA:
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/01f56d99-7b66-41d8-9e32-301ff4dddf66/get-newly-created-list-item-id-from-within-a-workflow?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: That ist not what I want. If I create a new Item, I need the ItemID of an older Item which the same "Title" in the same list.